# Auto send text message on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sms

I have been asked to send text message(sms) automatically when there is data changed in a table on mysql.. I have been searched many times and it comes with trigger..

I was wondering how mysql will send the text message(sms).. is it using gammu or somethingelse?

Thank you anyway for the response..

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any builtin functionality to send SMS messages.

As your search revealed, we can use a TRIGGER to perform actions whenever a row is inserted, updated or deleted from a table. One of the possible actions the trigger might perform is to INSERT a row to another table.

A separate component (not the MySQL database) could connect to the database and periodically poll that other table, and send SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices here, none of them wonderful.

One is to write a program in some application language (php or java, perhaps) to poll the dbms looking for changes in a table. Then it can send the requisite messages.   You can do this by putting a time-updated timestamp in each row of the table. Then your polling will query for rows changed since the last time the polling ran.  If you run this query once every six seconds, for example, you'll be no more than a tenth of a minute out of date with these SMS messages. That probably works for most wireless-network SMS.

Another is to add a user-defined function to MySQL and then invoke that function from a trigger. This one, for example, sends a message to a message queuing system like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/index.html). https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stomp

You could then write a queue consumer app to send your SMS messages. This approach has low latency and will scale up nicely. But, it requires extending MySQL, and rigging up a nontrivial queuing system.

A third approach is to get the software that updates your table also to send the SMS messages.